# How to specify that we're qualifying exactly that variant member?

Tags: ssl, struct, rfc

I have a question about `TLS 1.0` rfc:

Consider the following structure:

```
enum { apple, orange } VariantTag;
struct {
    select (VariantTag) { /* value of selector is implicit */
         case apple: V1;   /* VariantBody, tag = apple */
         case orange: V2;  /* VariantBody, tag = orange */
    } variant_body;       /* optional label on variant */
} VariantRecord;
```

TLS 1.0 [RFC2246](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt) `4.6.1 Variants` says:

> For example, a

```
orange VariantRecord
```

> is a narrowed type of a VariantRecord containing a
>   variant_body of type V2.

But how can we narrow the following structure:

```
enum { apple, orange } VariantTag;
enum { cherry, potato } AnotherTag;
struct {
   select (VariantTag) { 
         case apple: V1; 
         case orange: V2;
   } variant_body;  

   select (AnotherTag) { 
         case cherry: V3; 
         case potato: V4;
   } another_body;  
}
```

contating a `variant_body` of type `V2`and `another_body` of type `V4?